# PHPs ldap_bind() failing even though ldap_connect() is successful

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

As stated in the title the ldap_connect() functions works fine but when I try to use ldap_bind(), anonymous and with credentials PHP will just give me

> Can't contact LDAP server

How do I debug this issue further?

When using a ldap browser I can connect and bind without any issues and it seems that there are no further error messages.

I try to bind using protocol version 3.

Comment: Do you run the ldap-browser from the same machine the PHP is executed on?

Answer (score 1):

`ldap_connect` does **not** actually connect to the LDAP server but merely checks whether what you provide as parameter "makes sense". So it would fail when you provide f.e. 300.300.300.300 as IP-Address. But that's it. There is **no** connection tried, even though the function is called `ldap_connect`. That has historic reasons.

The first try to connect is usually done on `ldap_bind` which is the reason that connection issues usually surface here.

Note that you should use an LDAP-URI as parameter for `ldap_connect`. The second parameter (`$port`) is deprecated and will only be used when you pass an IP-address or an FQDN as first parameter (which you should not do as you then can't specify f.e. LDAPS). So you should have something like `ldap_connect('ldaps://ldap.example.org:639');`.

I'm usually first checking via `fsockopen` whether I can reach the server on the given port like this: ```

```
$res = fsockopen('ldap.example.org', 639, null, null, 5);
if (false === $res) {
    throw new Exception('server could not be reached within 5 seconds');
}
fclose($res);
```

When no exception is thrown, the server is available and it's more likely that the credentials are wrong.

Apart from that you can always use `ldap_error` and `ldap_errno` to (usually) get more detailed information about the last error.